# How to generate core dump when use Address Sanitizer and gcc7.1.0

Tags: gcc, coredump, address-sanitizer

I compiled my code with `-fsanitize=address` on centOS 7.2.1511. When I updated gcc to 7.1.0, it can't generate core dump file anymore. Can anybody help me?

gcc compile options:

```
-lm -g3 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas --std=c++11 -Werror -ggdb -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

link options:

```
-lxml2 -lpthread -lmysqlclient -L/usr/lib64/mysql/ -llog4cxx -lprotobuf -llua -lluabind -lhiredis -lcrypto -lcurl -ljsoncpp -Wl,-E -fsanitize=address -ldl
```

When I used gcc 4.8.5, core dump was normally generated with the option ASAN_OPTIONS set like this:

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS="disable_core=0:unmap_shadow_on_exit=1:abort_on_error=1"
```

When I updated gcc to 7.1.0, core dump can't generate anymore, even if the ASAN_OPTIONS is set like above.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is solved.The new sanitizer option ASAN_OPTIONS should be set is "disable_coredump",I set it like this:

```
ASAN_OPTIONS="disable_coredump=0:unmap_shadow_on_exit=1:abort_on_error=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in theory it should've worked like this:

1. `ulimit -c unlimited` of course (optionally adjust `sysctl kernel.core_pattern`)
2. `export ASAN_OPTIONS=disable_coredump=0,abort_on_error=1`
3. run, obtain the core (ideally, if all works).

However, I've tried quite a few more combinations of `disable_coredump=0`, `halt_on_error=1`, `abort_on_error=1`, `handle_abort=0` -- all I got each time was just an annoying ASAN error (@ LLVM 8, commit 1473e85213404eccb4d018d41c24d2f5834f81b5):

> `nested bug in the same thread, aborting.`

and exit code 1 (no core). From what little glimpses at the source that I've taken, it seems that asan handles that same SIGABRT that it emitted, but interpreting that as a crash-while-handling-a-crash. Not quite exactly what `-help` said; a thing to improve, perhaps.

---

Still, I was able to circumvent this itchy-bitchy error handling with one more option:

```
ASAN_OPTIONS+=:sleep_before_dying=150
```

and then, when it sleeped as instructed, **hit `^\` in the terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>, the equivalent of `kill -QUIT`).

That, finally, produced the core file I've been trying to get.

Comment: Thank you!  Still hitting this "nested bug in the same thread" thing in gcc 8.3.1.  I was beginning to go a little crazy.  :-(

Comment: @MikeAndrews welcome! :) Let me suggest to channel that frustration into a constructive bug report, *"abort_on_error doesn't work"* or something similar. https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues might be a good starting point.

Comment: Already reported here https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1072